# Looping through an array of arrays and creating an array from incremented values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, increment

Hello I have a foreach question. I am trying to loop through an array of arrays, and as each  array goes through, the values

```php
$alreadyhere = 0;
$nothere = 0;
$addedNewMember = 0;
$addedTagToExistingMember = 0;
```

will update and increment. At the end of the code, these values get put into the `$returnArr` Array.  What I am trying to do is make a final array called `allStats[]`; that holds all of the `$return[]` arrays . I've tried to loop through in different ways and add all the return arrays , but I can't get my head around the logic.

```php
if($newArray){

    $allStats = array();
 
    foreach($newArray as $arrs){

        $alreadyhere = 0;
        $nothere = 0;
        $addedNewMember = 0;
        $addedTagToExistingMember = 0;
    
        foreach($arrs as $arry2){

            //do code and increment values

            $returnArr = [
                'newMembersCount' => $addedNewMember,
                'updatedMembersCount' => $addedTagToExistingMember,
                'existingMembersCount' => $alreadyhere,
                'missingMembersCount' => $nothere,
                'method' => $method
            ];
        
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to loop through through and create this one array that holds all the return arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by the following code. The inner `loop` increments the values and the final result is appended to `$allStats` `array` in the end.

```
$allStats = array();
if ($newArray) {
    foreach ($newArray as $arrs) {
        $alreadyhere = 0;
        $nothere = 0;
        $addedNewMember = 0;
        $addedTagToExistingMember = 0;

        foreach ($arrs as $arry2) {
            //do code and increment values
        }

        $allStats[] = [
            'newMembersCount' => $addedNewMember,
            'updatedMembersCount' => $addedTagToExistingMember,
            'existingMembersCount' => $alreadyhere,
            'missingMembersCount' => $nothere,
            'method' => $method
        ];
    }
}

return $allStats;
```